# For variables names for text components ending with a dot(.) , itextpdf appends .widget to them

Tags: itextpdf

For variable names that i am declaring using pdf expro, having dot(.) character at the end, the itext is appending "Widget" to them. IF my variable name on pdf template for a textbox is "Payment transaction no." then itextpdf makes it as "Payment Transaction No.Widget"

Why does this happen ? and suggestions about handling it, because as a part of data validation i need to pick up pdf field names and validate them with those saved in form configuration settings in the database.

Is there any other such kind of wierd possibility that might occur ? Please provide those cases.

Comment: *Why does this happen ?* - Dots may not be used in a field name. Merely if you build a hierarchy of fields, dots shall be used to build the path.

Comment: so whats the concept behind appending "Widget" to it and what does this mean?

Comment: The concept is **Garbage in** (Simple field names endingin a dot), **Garbage our** (anything weird). If you present a broken PDF (and a field name ending with a dot is broken) to some PDF processor, anything may happen.